# How can transform UTM Geographical coordinates from Zone 19 to Zone 18?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, utm

I want to transform UTM Geographical coordinates from Zone 19  to Zone 18 in southern hemisphere. How can I do it using QGIS?

5622274 -   249667  Zone 19S  Datum 1984

5623190 - 249646  Zone 19S  Datum 1984

I can do it in ArcGIS using Project (data managment) and saving the shape zone 19 as zone 18. In order to see the new coordinates, in atributte table I make 2 colummns , X and Y (float), then I use geometry to calculate x coordinate of point (meters) and the same for y on the second column.

Comment: QGIS and Python might be two completely different answers.  Please **edit** the question to contain exactly one topic, and include your research on how to do this reprojection.

Comment: Note that the first value is the "northing" (y) and the second value is the "easting" (x). "datum 1984" implies WGS84 as the geographic CRS / datum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the layer and hit 'Save as' in the menu that comes up.

One option will be 'CRS' you can open a dialog box here and search for the coordinate system you are looking for.

Once you have set the desired CRS and set the path and file name for the new re-projected dataset, just hit ok and the layer will now be reprojected.

Load this new layer into QGIS, open the attribute table and click the field calculator button. This defaults to add a new field, so simply create one field called x with a field type of 'Decimal number' and set appropriate field length & precision. Now in the expression box type

```
$x
```

Repeat this for the y coordinate (exchange x for y in what I wrote above).

Now you will have the attribute table populated with the new coordiates

Comment: That work perfect!!! thanks a lot!!! @Freight_Train